# InnoSetup - edit files

Tags: batch-file, installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to edit a file using a batch loaded via innosetup, but it doesn't work. (it works only if i run it ALONE with admin privileges). Setting privileges to admin in [setup] doesn't fix it.

I read that it's possible to make some operation directly in the compiler.

The batch was doing one simple thing:
copy file1.lsp+file2.lsp file1.lsp
it merges 2 file and overwrite the fist one.
The second file contains 10 row that i want to add the file 1, which is in the computer.

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Are you sure the batch is really being executed? Do you receive any error message?

Comment: i added a pause at and of it, it says that it can't find the directory (??).. but if i run it by hand, it works (with admin privileges)

Comment: Which directory can't be found? Are you sure it has already been created? Do you use relative paths? Are you sure the working directory is correct?

Comment: The problem seems to be the missing absolute path. But anyway, I would do it [from code](http://pastebin.com/Qg77yC3T). There is nothing that could be done in batch script but not in Inno Setup natively.

Comment: batch contains: copy "%ProgramFiles%\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp"+"C:COBIAX\Cordoli\cobiax_path.lsp" "%ProgramFiles%\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp"

and when running it via Inno it says "impossibile to find the specified path"

Comment: if i run the same batch by hand: C:\Windows\system32> copy "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp"+"C:COBIAX\Cordoli\cobiax_path.lsp" "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp"
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp
        1 file copied.

Comment: None of what you've posted in your last comments would work (the drive root of the appended file is wrong). And the first uses `%ProgramFiles%` variables, so they differ. But anyway, for this you will most likely need admin elevation. And still, I would suggest doing it from code rather than batch script.

Comment: i don't know how to do with code.. can you help me?

Comment: When do you perform this operation ? As a post-installation step ?

Comment: [Run]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: /i {app}\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi

Filename: "{app}\batch.bat" ; StatusMsg: "Aggiungendo il percorso sicuro."

Comment: TLama, I opened your code.. but i'm a totally newbie. WHere have I to put my paths? 
thanks

Comment: got it!
begin
AppendFile ('C:\COBIAX\cobiax_path.lsp', 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad2016.lsp');
end.

Comment: i don't know how to run it... 
http://i.imgur.com/HRWAofc.png

Comment: So as a post-installation step after `[Run]` section is processed. Then you can do it [like this](http://pastebin.com/4hLCncUC).

Comment: WOW it works!!!! Thanks guy, I'll learn pascal to get independent :)
a last question:
is it possible to search if the content of this file is already inside the other, and skip the copy in this case? thank

Comment: and how should it be in the case it's pre-installation?